# The relationship between a buildpack and a slug compiler in Heroku

Tags: heroku

Now I am searching Heroku, which is a famous Paas platform. And here is one question about the internal structure, especially a relationship between a buildpack and a slug compiler.
In public statement,

"Buildpacks are responsible for transforming deployed code into a slug, which can then be executed on a dyno. Buildpacks are composed of a set of scripts, and depending on the programming language, the scripts will retrieve dependencies, output generated assets or compiled code, and more. This output is assembled into a slug by the slug compiler."

And in "Leaning Heroku Postgres", which is a book introducing Heroku's details and published by PACKT enterprise, the author says "the slug is created by the slug compiler and its core is a collection of scripts called a buildpack."

So, what does buildpack do in Heroku?   In the former statement, it is supposed to transform deployed app into a slug and in the later one  buildpack is the core of the slug compiler which is supposed to create a slug. 
Which creates a slug, the buildpack or the slug compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Heroku, the buildpack generates the slug. It is the 'slug compiler'. I think you're getting a bit caught up on the terminology here though.

The way Heroku works is quite simple:

- When you push your code to Heroku, a buildpack runs and installs dependencies, caches static assets, etc.
- The buildpack then puts all of this into what is essentially a zipfile on Amazon S3.
- When a dyno starts up, Heroku downloads the zipfile from S3 with everything that's needed (your app dependencies, source code, etc.), then starts the server up.

That's basically it!

Comment: In your explanation, a slug is the zip file placed in S3 in your second item, isn't? And a slug compiler is equal to a buildpack? Totally same?

Comment: A buildpack just 'builds' a slug. That's all it does. A slug itself is just a zip file that's stored in Amazon S3.

Comment: Thank you.  I became more clear, so is a slug complier equal to a buildpack? I assume one of a slug compiler's components is a buildpack , which excutes the transformation.